# Concatenate multiple launchpad repositories

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, bazaar, launchpad

I want to download many addresses at once with `bzr branch`, i tried several things, but nothing seems to be working.

Tried a `file.sh` with this kind of structure:

```
sudo bzr branch lp:~jmarquez/openerp-tecvemar/tcv_bank_deposit  lp:~jmarquez/openerp-   tecvemar/initial_stock lp:~jmarquez/openerp-tecvemar/tcv_sale  lp:~jmarquez/openerp-    tecvemar/tcv_mrp lp:~jmarquez/openerp-tecvemar/tcv_label_request lp:~jmarquez/openerp-  tecvemar/tcv_check_voucher  
lp:~jmarquez/openerp-tecvemar/tcv_stock
```

But when I execute `file.sh` it just doesn't works, can't read the other paths after 1st one, is there some particular command in `bzt`to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to download multiple branches at once.

But you can rewrite your script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

localrepo=/tmp/repo
bzr init-repo $localrepo
cd $localrepo

baseurl=lp:~jmarquez/openerp-tecvemar
for branch in tcv_bank_deposit initial_stock tcv_sale tcv_mrp tcv_label_request tcv_check_voucher tcv_stock; do
    bzr branch $baseurl/$branch
done
```

Change the path in `localrepo` as you like. It's important to create a *shared repository* with `bzr init-repo` to contain the branches. This way the common revisions in the branches can be shared, which will save disk space and speed up your download.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly! So, there is a way to do it!